# Why do I can not use jquery contents() to find my dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to give my table custom tooltip.So I give each `td` a class called `trigger1`.And each td hava a custom tooltipcontent which is default hide.Now I add the mouseover and mouseout event,but I find it not work.When I remove the `contents()`,and it work well.Can anyone tell me the reason?When should I use `contents()`?

```
 $(function(){
 $(".trigger1").each(function () { 
        $(this).on('mouseover', function () { 
  //not work: $(this).contents().find(".tooltipcontent").show();            
  $(this).find(".tooltipcontent").show(); 
        });
        $(this).on('mouseout', function () {
             /*not work: $(this).contents().find(".tooltipcontent").hide(); */
            $(this).find(".tooltipcontent").hide(); 
        });
    }); 
});
```

And each td content is like this:

```
  <td align="center" class="trigger1">
   <a target="_blank" href="#">1234511</a> 
   <div class="tooltipcontent" style="display: none;">
      some content
      <a  target="_blank" href="#">more</a>
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: beacuse `$(this).contents()`  returns a javascript array, and its 'find()' method is not the same as $(this)'s `find()` [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [jQuery **.contents()** documentation](https://api.jquery.com/contents/), the difference between `.contents()` and `.children()` is that `.contents()` also returns text and comment elements, which the vast majority of jQuery methods do not support.

You are almost certainly confused by using it. Replacing your instances of `.contents()` with `.children()` will work in the manner you desire, like this:

```
$(this).children('.tooltipcontent').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method is a better way.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/fgma3bt6/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.trigger1').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.tooltipcontent').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.tooltipcontent').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this).contents() will return an array of child nodes including text and comment nodes. You will not be able to find class tooltipcontent directly. Change

```
$(this).contents().find(".tooltipcontent")
```

to

```
$(this).children('.tooltipcontent') or $(this).find(".tooltipcontent")
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not relevant to question.

You don't have to use jquery on this, you could use css to achieve same effect. try this:

CSS:

```
 .trigger1:hover .tooltipcontent{ display: block )
```